# I can't open apps already installed (desktop entries are missed - almost all)

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have the following issue.

I can't find many apps using dock search but it's already installed.

ex: I've searched for **calculator**
[image: no results for calulator] 
I opened software center and calculator already installed.
[image: calculator already installed]
When I opened calculator from it I found that icon is missed on the dock
[image: missed apps icons]

I also opened `~/.local/share/applications` and I found desktops entries for chrome only.

**Note:** the I have the issue with **manually installed** apps from **software center** like **vscode** or using **apt** like **terminator**.

Comment: Look inside `/snap/` directory, you should find a `.desktop` launcher somewhere. Does copying it to `~/.local/share/applications/` fix your issue?

Comment: There are many directories inside it. and directories contain other directories. I didn't find `.desktop` files in these directories contain

Comment: I did it. but no `.desktop` file appears.

Comment: What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `find /snap -name  "*.desktop"`?

Comment: I found many results, which one should I copy ex: `/snap/gnome-calculator/170/meta/gui/gnome-calculator.desktop` and '/snap/gnome-calculator/170/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop' and other files are located at the same path but the number `170` changes for every path

Comment: Try copying `/snap/gnome-calculator/170/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop` to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

Comment: I did copy both `meta/gui/` and `usr/share/` but nothing changes.
Note: this issue not limited for calculator and also not limited for snap apps.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if you have only chrome entries in your .local/share/applications directory.

In the directory **/usr/share/applications** you should find your files.

A good description can be found on
[on this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103213/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-gnome-window-manager)

Comment: Calculator application that comes pre-installed with 18.04 is a snap application. You won't find a `.desktop` launcher for it in `/usr/share/applications/` either.